# off-the-shelf web application working directory

Tags: java, spring, deployment, web.xml

I've just started working with Spring/java web. I'm wondering how to accomplish following scenario:

Let's say that I'm creating an application which supports file upload, uses a database connection and maybe a web service. This is an off-the-shelf system, so all the settings are customer specific and should be configured by customer's IT people on the deployment time.

More general in the web.xml file I would like to point the application working directory containing uploaded files, license key file, configuration files, other customer specific resources and maybe even fragments of spring context.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>workdir</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/r2/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In my application I would like use the workdir value in order to include configuration files ...

```
<import resource="wordir_param_value/settings.properties" />
```

context config fragments

```
<import resource="wordir_param_value/security.xml"/>
```

And how may I later use these values in the java code? What is "the best" approach in case like this anyway (off-the-shelf application config)?

Best Regards,
Alek

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's property support for that. This allowed two different approaches:

- Having a property file outside the application (at a fixed location), the admin can edit it, and the application loads it
- In a Tomcat you can write properties in the application specific context.XML file

In the code use @value annotation to inject the properties in a variable.

In the spring XML file you use it with `${name}`
Of course you need to configure the proprtyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: But how do you use this property in the spring context xml file: `<import resource="<workdir_param_value>/security.xml"/>` Can you show a line of code?